# How to set up database password for a Symfony project hosted at platform.sh?

Tags: database, symfony, security, platform

I have a Symfony 3 project, which is hosted at platform.sh. As a default configuration they provide me with a connection to database which is not secured by password. I've found the following lines in documentation but can't get what do they really mean:

> In either case, you will also need the service credentials. For that, run platform relationships. That will give output similar to the following:

```
database:
    -
        username: user
        scheme: mysql
        service: mysqldb
        ip: 120.0.80.37
        cluster: yuh7waly3uu6n-master-7rqtwti
        host: database.internal
        rel: mysql
        path: main
        query:
            is_master: true
        password: ''
        port: 3306
```

> That indicates that the database relationship can be accessed at host database.internal, user user, and an empty password. The path key contains the database name, main. The other values can be ignored.

It is written here: https://docs.platform.sh/configuration/services.html#obtaining-service-credentials

Does it mean that if I want to change these credentials, I need to type proper password to the services.yaml file or it is just a way the server will try to connect. How can I change this empty password to something secure? Can it be solved by Environmental Variables or the approach with services.yaml changing is the correct one?

Comment: *if* you have the current symfony (or since 3.4) then the DATABASE_URL environment variable will be used by default. it is referenced in `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` (or app/config/...)

Comment: @Jakumi, unfortunately, platform.sh overrides default Symfony's configuration in app_parameters by own *.yaml files. So, that doesn't work this way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long conversation with support, I've realized that it's **impossible** to do in a non-premium account. They were asking me to change the type and this is the only way to solve this issue.